# How to sort python array of arrays

Tags: python, hpsa

I want to sort a python array based one the first value of each sub-array
[[1437510001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016380001', 'loc-stuff-39400016380001'], 
[1437500001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016370001', 'loc-stuff-39400016370001'], 
[1437490001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016360001', 'loc-stuff-39400016360001'], 
[1437480001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016350001', 'loc-stuff-39400016350001'], 
[1437520001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016390001', 'loc-stuff-39400016390001']]

These arrays I deal with are usually a maximum of 200.

Basically what I need to do is sort largest down to smallest value.

D

Answer (score 1):

In Python, sequences are [compared lexicographically](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types), meaning "first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted".

So in your case you can simply use a plain call to `list.sort`. And since you want to sort largest to smallest, use the `reverse=True` keyword arg:

```
lst.sort(reverse=True)
```

This sorts the list in place. If you want to leave `lst` unchanged and return a new sorted list, use:

```
sorted_list = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
>>> mylist = [[1437510001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016380001', 'loc-stuff-39400016380001'], [1437500001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016370001', 'loc-stuff-39400016370001'], [1437490001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016360001', 'loc-stuff-39400016360001'], [1437480001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016350001', 'loc-stuff-39400016350001'], [1437520001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016390001', 'loc-stuff-39400016390001']]
>>> mylist.sort()
>>> print mylist
[[1437480001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016350001', 'loc-stuff-39400016350001'], [1437490001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016360001', 'loc-stuff-39400016360001'], [1437500001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016370001', 'loc-stuff-39400016370001'], [1437510001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016380001', 'loc-stuff-39400016380001'], [1437520001L, 'UNLOCK_SRV_BIND_ACCOUNT-39400016390001', 'loc-stuff-39400016390001']]
```

Comment: Because you (almost) never need to use `key=itemgetter(0)` for sorting, because Python sequences are [compared lexicographically](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types): "first the first two items are compared, and if they differ this determines the outcome of the comparison; if they are equal, the next two items are compared, and so on, until either sequence is exhausted". So you can simply use `mylist.sort()` here.